# Order a dictionary to get a chain of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I couldn't find any clue how to solve this problem.

A function from an SDK generated a dictionary like this:

```
myDict = {('c3','4'):20,('1','2a'):5,('4','5'):1,('2a','c3'):8}
```

I would like to be able to order the dictionary to get:

```
myDict = {('1','2a'):5, ('2a','c3'):8, ('c3','4'):20, ('4','5'):1}
```

Where the first member of the following key tuple is the same as the second member of the preceding key tuple.

I'm working on Mind Maps with Xmind, and this allows me to follow a chain of relations between nodes.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered and can't be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that dictionaries are unordered so you need to use another (ordered) data structure, for example an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Actually making the connections isn't easy in the general case. In your case it's possible so I'll present a solution that works for your type of problem:

```
inp = {('c3', '4'): 20, 
       ('1', '2a'): 5, 
       ('4', '5'): 1, 
       ('2a', 'c3'): 8}

# Collect the start and end points
starts = {}
ends = {}
for key in inp:
    start, end = key
    starts[start] = key
    ends[end] = key

print(starts)
# {'1': ('1', '2a'), '2a': ('2a', 'c3'), '4': ('4', '5'), 'c3': ('c3', '4')}
print(ends)
# {'2a': ('1', '2a'), '4': ('c3', '4'), '5': ('4', '5'), 'c3': ('2a', 'c3')}

# Find the ultimate start point - that's the tricky step in general, 
# but it's easy in your case.
startpoint = set(starts).difference(ends)
startpoint = next(iter(startpoint))   # yeah, it's a bit ugly to get the one and only item of a set...
print(startpoint)
# '1'

# Find the connections
from collections import OrderedDict

res = OrderedDict()
while startpoint in starts:
    tup = starts[startpoint]
    res[tup] = inp[tup]
    startpoint = tup[1]  # next start point

print(res)
# OrderedDict([(('1', '2a'), 5), (('2a', 'c3'), 8), (('c3', '4'), 20), (('4', '5'), 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered set** of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

[docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), emphasis mine

You can however convert your `dict` into `tuple` and have it sorted:

```
my_sorted_tuple = sorted(my_dict.items())
```